# Digital signature with Big Brother

Tags: encryption, authentication, rsa, diffie-hellman

I have [read](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G99Pel3FxzwVLzD7CWsYPp2t5r9JLiAB/view?usp=drivesdk) digital signature with Big Brother but don't understand the sequence.

> One approach to digital signatures is to have a central authority that
> knows everything and whom everyone trusts, say Big Brother $(BB).$Each
> user then chooses a secret key and carries it by hand to $BB$'s office.
> Thus, only Alice and $BB$ know Alice's secret key, $K_A$, and so on.
>
> When Alice wants to send a signed plaintext message, $P$, to her banker,
> Bob, she generates $K_A(B, R_A, t, P)$, where $B$ is Bob's identity, $R_A$ is a
> random number chosen by Alice, $t$ is a timestamp to ensure freshness,
> and $K_A(B, R_A, t, P)$ is the message encrypted with her key, $K_A.$

After then I don't understand how the following sequence works because there is nothing explained. Can anyone please explain in detail?

Comment: When quoting from a source, please cite the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alice - knowing $K_A$ - sends $K_A(B, R_A, t, P)$ to $BB$.

$BB$ - knowing $K_A$ - decrypts $K_A(B, R_A, t, P)$, obtaining $(B, R_A, t, P)$.

$BB$ - knowing $K_B$ and $K_{BB}$ - sends $K_B(A, R_A, t, P, K_{BB}(A, t, P))$ to Bob.

Bob - knowing $K_B$ - decrypts $K_B(A, R_A, t, P, K_{BB}(A, t, P))$, obtaining $(A, R_A, t, P, K_{BB}(A, t, P))$.

At this point you can go on reading.

Comment: could you explain little, I don't understand what is happening here..

Comment: Maybe you don't understand the notation: $K_A(M)$ means encrypting the message $M$ using the key $K_A$. I usually write it as $Enc(M,K_A)$.

Comment: all things are understood. But in last paragraph "Trudy replaying either message "-- what does mean by replaying message?

Comment: It means trying to impersonate Alice by sending to Bob copies of messages sent by Alice to Bob.

Comment: @Riccardo here middle in attack is impossible because everything is encrypted?

Comment: A man-in-the-middle can only forward messages that he intercepts, but he can't impersonate $BB$ since he doesn't know others' private keys.

Comment: @Riccardo but how Alice got fooled?

Comment: If Bob does not check for freshness of a message, he could be tricked to repeat an action that he has already taken. This is why $t$ and $R_A$ are used.

Comment: @Riccardo I want to how A got attacked by any attacker?

Comment: The only one that can attack $A$ is $BB$, but we are assuming that $BB$ is honest.

Comment: @Riccardo when $A$ is attack by $BB$, we can't caught $BB$, inspite of using timestamp. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, this is the problem with a central authority: you have to blindly trust it.

Comment: @Riccardo So, my question is Alice has not attacking chance except by BB, when A is attack by BB timestamp is useless, why we use timestamp?

Comment: As I said before, the timestamp is used to prove the freshness of the message to Bob.

Comment: @Riccardo "freshness of the message" means message without repeating. Alice doesn't sent any repeating message. Trudy who may be the attacker send the replay message. My question is how Trudy may be pretend as Alice? . So Alice is fooled by Trudy. Am I right?

Comment: There is nothing in the system that identifies the participants, so Trudy can simply say to Bob: "Hi, I am $BB$ and this is a message from Alice". If Bob does not check the message freshness, he could be fooled.

Comment: @Riccardo  how Trudy can get message which is repeating message sent by Alice?

Comment: We always assume that an attacker can intercept messages, since the communication channel is insecure.

Comment: @Riccardo intercepter could be exist between Alice and BB or BB and Bob or BB could be treated as interceptor? Am I right?

Comment: Yes, perfectly right.